# Scala sbt file dependency from github repository

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

Is it possible to include a dependency from github?
The repository does not have a jar file, just a build.sbt file and a source folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new project which points to the source in your `build.sbt` and then use `dependsOn`:

```
lazy val projectIDependOn = RootProject(uri("git://github.com/user/Project.git"))

lazy val myProject = project in file("my-project").dependsOn(projectIDependOn)
```

An alternative approach would be to clone to github repository and then use [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) to create an uber JAR you can use, but that requires a bit more work.

Comment: where do i place that? In my main method?

Comment: In your `build.sbt` file.

Comment: That gives errors, my build.sbt looks like this:
scalaVersion := "2.12.1"
scalacOptions ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-feature")

libraryDependencies += ...

Comment: then add a method call: `dependsOn(projectIDependOn)`

Comment: Look at my edit to your post, this is what I have and it does not gives errors. I assume it works, but how do you now import/refer to this code? I'm trying this repo: https://github.com/otobrglez/regressor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135601/discussion-between-captain-obvious-and-yuval-itzchakov).

Comment: It seems there was a version issue, downgrading my root project to 2.11 instead of 2.12 solved the issues. The final code in my build.sbt:

```lazy val projectIDependOn = RootProject(uri("git://github.com/project.git"))
dependsOn(projectIDependOn)```

Comment: Is it possible to specify a tag or commit hash?