# How to add a github library in a scala project (IntelliJ Idea)

Tags: scala, github, intellij-idea

I need to use a github library in my scala project (IntelliJ Idea). I am trying to add the jar file to the project using File->Project Structure-> Modules -> Dependencies -> Jars. But When I try to use the methods from that library, I see that they are in red color which means that the library is not recognized. I am trying to insert a declaration of the library in the pom.xml file, but the problem is that the library is not defined by maven. Also, I found suggestions to add the jar file to the libs directory. However, in my scala project structure, there is no libs directory. I have created a libs directory and added the jar file with a specific pom.xml to this jar but I got the same error.

How can I proceed?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project help?

Comment: CrazyCoder Thank you. I used the proposed solution to build the jar file in my scala project. I think that it work.

Comment: With sbt https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550376/how-can-sbt-pull-dependency-artifacts-from-git https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42206668/scala-sbt-file-dependency-from-github-repository https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22432666/how-can-sbt-project-import-library-from-github-cloned-to-local-directory